# Why is Caesar good in the first Planet of the Apes and bad in the 2001 film?

Tags: character, planet-of-the-apes, planet-of-the-apes-2001

Why is Caesar good in the first Planet of the Apes and bad in the 2001 film? And how can Caesar from the 1973 movie be still alive in 2670 even if he was born in the 1970s?

Are those stories different?

Comment: Those are two different questions, and thus should not be combined.

Comment: Define "good" and "Bad"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why is Caesar good in the first Planet of the apes and bad in the 2001?**

Because both are different films and didn't serve canon to each other. Both are based on the same novels but they have adaptational changes.

Original film series was

- Planet of the Apes (1968)
- Beneath the Planet of the Apes (1970)
- Escape from the Planet of the Apes (1971)
- Conquest of the Planet of the Apes (1972)
- Battle for the Planet of the Apes(1973)

But the 2001 film [Planet of the Apes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_of_the_Apes_%282001_film%29) was the reboot of the franchise and a stand-alone film, it was expected to be a new film series but it got rebooted again with [Rise of the Planet of the Apes (2011)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rise_of_the_Planet_of_the_Apes).

So both the Caesar from original film series and 2001's are different interpretation of the same character from book.

For the whole franchise, refer [my own answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/50617/1190) to similar question.

For the age of [Caesar](http://planetoftheapes.wikia.com/wiki/Caesar_(APJ)), in the original film series he was born on 1973 and died at 2070 (approximately). So he lived for 97 years which is long for a Ape but he was not a normal Ape and human can live till 100 years. So we can consider it normal in this extreme circumstances .